# Is it possible to put a trendline on a Google Barchart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, bar-chart, google-visualization

I am trying to put a trendline on a barchart. When I add the trendline to the options, no trendline appears. Is there a way make a trendline on a barchart like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2014', 1000, 400],
      ['2015', 1170, 460],
      ['2016', 660, 1120],
      ['2017', 1030, 540]
    ]);

    var options = {
    trendlines: {
        0: {
            color: 'green',
        visibleInLegend: true,
        }
    },
      chart: {
        title: 'Last 7 Days',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'vertical',
      vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
      height: 400,
      colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));


  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** `trendlines.*` are listed among [the several options that don't work on *Material* charts](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

*Material* chart --> `packages: ['bar']` -- `google.charts.Bar`

however, *there is a way to make a trendline on a barchart*, using...

*Core* chart --> `packages: ['corechart']` -- `google.visualization.ColumnChart`

you can use the following config option to get the chart *close* to the look & feel of *Material*

`theme: 'material'`

**2.** for `trendlines.*` to work on a *Core* chart, it must be built on a [*Continuous* axis](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous)

meaning the axis values cannot be strings

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 1), 1000, 400],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 1), 1170, 460],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 1), 660, 1120],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 1), 1030, 540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02'],
    hAxis: {
      format: 'yyyy',
      ticks: [new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 0, 1), new Date(2017, 0, 1)]
    },
    height: 400,
    theme: 'material',
    title: 'Last 7 Days',
    trendlines: {
      0: {
        color: 'green',
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      format: 'decimal'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```